# GAE two entry points

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having trouble finding the docs on how to setup two application entry points in GAE:

```
    runtime: php72

    env_variables:
      APP_ENV: prod
      APP_SECRET: XXX
      # APP_DEBUG: true

      ## For connecting to Cloud SQL with Doctrine
      ## This is used in part two of the README:

      DATABASE_URL: XXX


    handlers:
      # Image DB delivery
      - url: /image
        script: public/image/index.php

      # Declare the build and bundles directory as static assets to be served by the App Engine CDN.
      - url: /build
        static_dir: public/build
      - url: /assets
        static_dir: public/assets
      - url: /bundles
        static_dir: public/bundles

      # Declare any media files in the public directory as static assets as well.
      - url: /(.*\.(ico|txt|gif|png|jpg))$
        static_files: public/\1
        upload: public/.*\.(ico|txt|gif|png|jpg)$
```

Gives me an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: script field for handler
>   '/image' must be set to 'auto' for runtime php72.

I am using Symfony 4+ so I already have /public/index.php which is handling requests just fine...but I have a simple image/index.php to load images without the overhead of S4...works fine locally but pushed to cloud GAE pukes...what gives?

Comment: can you post the rest of your yml and other configs?

Comment: I've added what its was...I've had a few variations - none of which seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

In the php72 runtime you cannot use this statement:

```
    script: public/image/index.php
```

From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#handlers_element):

> script
>
> Optional. Specifies that requests to the specific handler should
>   target your app. The only accepted value for the **script** element is
>   **auto** because all traffic is served using the entrypoint command. In
>   order to use static handlers, at least one of your handlers must
>   contain the line **script: auto** or define an **entrypoint** element to
>   deploy successfully.

So you should change `public/image/index.php` to `auto` in that statement.